# Firebase: How to know if a user used the app within 4 weeks

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase as a backend for my mobile app, how can I get the information (on the client side) if a user was using my mobile-app within the last 4 weeks or if he didn't?
I somehow need to get the date of last usage (last read, or write operation, last login...)

I know there is the information of "last sign-in" in the admin SDK, however I'm not sure if this is supposed to be integrated in the app itself.

Comment: I would set up a flag in the database with the last signed in timestamp and check against that.

Comment: How would you set that timestamp? You cannot include it in the login function, expecting that users never logout and, hence, almost never will call that function?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "using" I guess. I use the "resume" event to do things in the database. `document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);`

Comment: I'll have a look at this, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add `lastOnline` field to your user entity and change it everytime the user quit the application :

```
DatabaseReference userLastOnlineRef = FirebaseDatabse.getInstance().getReference("users/joe/lastOnline");
userLastOnlineRef.onDisconnect().setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

[link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#server-timestamps)

Comment: That sounds interesting. I will try that and let you know how it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you @Oussema Aroua. The `onDisconnect()` was exectly what I needed.